# SSRS data source: Can't use stored Windows credentials, "SharePoint does not use Windows authentication"

Tags: authentication, reporting-services, windows-authentication

I'm running a single-server deployment of SharePoint 2013 and SQL Server 2014 with SSRS in SharePoint-integrated mode. When trying to set up a subscription for a new report, I get a popup saying:

> Subscriptions cannot be created because credentials used to run this report are not stored.

Okay. So I pull up the properties for my data source, switch it to "Stored credentials", enter my `username/password` (just for testing purposes) and click "`Test Connection`", and get this error:

> The current action cannot be completed. The user data source credentials do not meet the requirements to run this report or shared dataset. Only Windows user credentials support 'Stored' or 'Prompt' options for a data extension that implements ITokenDataExtension for a report server configured in SharePoint integrated mode. Specify Windows credentials or configure the data source to use different options.

Fair enough. But when I tick "`Use as Windows credentials`", I get *this* error:

> **The data extension cannot use Windows credentials because SharePoint does not use Windows authentication.**

I don't know where to go from here. My SharePoint site is synced to the Active Directory for the domain on which it resides (which I don't have direct control over, I'm inside a larger managed development lab), the c2WTS service is installed and working, and I can run the report manually if the data source is set to "Windows authentication (integrated) or SharePoint user"; I did some googling and found that I can probably make the error go away if I rebuild my web app to use classic authentication instead of claims authentication, but since that's not the state of the production environment that's not a terribly useful fix. Isn't SSRS supposed to work with claims authentication anyway? Have I set something up wrong here?

**Edit**: I suppose it's worth mentioning that the data source is a SharePoint List type targeting the same site that the data source lives on.

Comment: Are you using NTLM or Keberos (WIA), FBA, or SAML for user auth? This article details the supported authentication mechanisms when working with the SharePoint List data source type. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee633650.aspx

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's whatever the default is (which I think is NTLM?) unless something else is being used at the AD level that's effecting my SharePoint install. I'm not a sysadmin and Kerberos, etc. are honestly a bit out of my depth.

Comment: Based on that article, if I'm running a web app using claims-based authentication there's basically no way whatsoever to use stored credentials on a SharePoint List data source? Which means there's basically no way to create a subscription to a report that uses SharePoint List data sources? What a nightmare.

Answer (score 0):

This may point you in the right direction: [Using Per-User Identity with Reporting Services and SharePoint](http://whitepages.unlimitedviz.com/2012/09/using-per-user-identity-with-reporting-services-and-sharepoint/)

Comment: That article seems to indicate that it's impossible to create subscriptions when using account impersonation. In any case, when I tick `Set execution context to this account` on the data source in SharePoint, I get an error "`The data extension supports Windows Integrated Security only.`"